# The three first Element in custom ListView are repeated and change position when scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom ListView and when I display it I get the 3 first element and they are repeated when I scroll. All the others elements are never display.

I have try with `setTag` and `getTag` but it doesnt work. The only way I found is to rebuild the view (disable the `if (row = null)`) each time I scroll on a element but I don't think it is a good thing to do.

This is my getView methode (with `setTag` and `getTag`) :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View row = convertView;
        Meal meal =  getItem(position);

        if (row == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nameMeal);
            holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageMeals);
            holder.price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
            holder.imgQuantity = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.hide);
            holder.soldOut = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sold_out);
            holder.descMenu = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.plus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            holder.minus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.minus);


            if (User.getInstance().imgBitMap.get(meal.nameFr) == null)
                new LoadImageFromURL(holder.img, meal).execute(meal.imageRealUrl);
            else
                holder.img.setImageBitmap(User.getInstance().imgBitMap.get(meal.nameFr));

            holder.txtTitle.setText(meal.nameFr);
            holder.price.setText(meal.price + "0 €");
            setButton(row, meal);
            setImage(row, meal);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.img.setTag(position);
        holder.plus.setTag(position);
        holder.minus.setTag(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setTag(position);
        holder.price.setTag(position);

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `convertView == null` you are setting the image and text views.  The `else` part means that the view is recycled so you don't have to inflate.  You *do*, however, have to do all your image and text setting there too.  So just take the image/text setting code out of the if block and move it after the if/else block so that it runs in either case.

Comment: "The else part means that the view is recycled so you don't have to inflate". Thanks I understand my mistake, it works well :)